# Exclude login from automated kill SQL job

Tags: sql, kill

I have this job that runs and kills blocking sessions that are longer than 10 mins. I understand that this approach is a bad idea in general.

Regardless, I now need to add a list of logins that are excluded from this job. I cannot seem to get it to exclude specific users in this script. Below is the script:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Table variable to hold InputBuffer data
DECLARE @Inputbuffer TABLE
(
  EventType NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
  Parameters INT NULL,
  EventInfo NVARCHAR(4000) NULL
)
-- Table variable to hold running processes information
DECLARE @BusyProcess TABLE
(
  SPID INT,
  Status VARCHAR(100),
  Login VARCHAR(100),
  HostName VARCHAR(100),
  DBName VARCHAR(100),
  Command VARCHAR(200),
  CPUTime INT,
  DiskIO INT,
  LastBatch DATETIME,
  ProgramName VARCHAR(200),
  EventInfo NVARCHAR(4000), -- extra column to hold actual stored procedure 
  or batch call text
  EventTime INT   -- time in minutes, a process is running
)
-- Insert all running processes information to table variable
INSERT  @BusyProcess
    ( SPID, Status, Login, HostName,  DBName, Command, CPUTime,
      DiskIO, LastBatch, ProgramName )

    SELECT spid,status,loginame,hostname,DB_NAME 
   (dbid),cmd,cpu,physical_io,last_batch,program_name 
    FROM SYS.SYSPROCESSES
    WHERE 
        1 = CASE WHEN Status IN ( 'RUNNABLE', 'SUSPENDED' ) 
   THEN 1
        --Transactions that are open not yet committed or 
rolledback
                    WHEN Status = 'SLEEPING' AND 
open_tran  > 0 THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 END
        AND cmd NOT LIKE 'BACKUP%'                  

-- Cursor to add actuall Procedure or Batch statement for each process

DECLARE cur_BusyProcess Cursor
FOR SELECT  SPID
    FROM    @BusyProcess

OPEN cur_BusyProcess 
DECLARE @SPID INT     

Fetch NEXT FROM cur_BusyProcess INTO @SPID
While ( @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1 )
BEGIN

    INSERT  @Inputbuffer
            EXEC ( 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + @SPID + ')'
                ) 

    UPDATE  @BusyProcess
    SET     EventInfo = I.EventInfo,
            EventTime = DATEDIFF(MI,LastBatch,GETDATE())
    FROM    @BusyProcess b
            CROSS JOIN @Inputbuffer i
    WHERE   B.SPID = @SPID


    DELETE  FROM @Inputbuffer

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_BusyProcess INTO @SPID
END
CLOSE cur_BusyProcess
DEALLOCATE cur_BusyProcess

-- Create html mail 
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM  @BusyProcess I
                    WHERE   EventInfo NOT LIKE '--
                                             -BusyProcess Detection%'
                    AND EventTime >= 3
                    )

BEGIN
Declare @Body varchar(max), @TableHead varchar(1000), @TableTail 
   varchar    (1000)
Set NoCount On;


Set @TableTail = '</table></body></html>';
Set @TableHead = '<html><head>' +
                  '<style>' +
                  'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-    left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-
size:11pt;} ' +
                  '</style>' +
                  '</head>' +
                  '<body><table cellpadding=0 
cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
                  '<tr><td align=center   
bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>ROW ID</b></td>' +
                  '<td align=center 
bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>SPID</b></td>' +
                  '<td align=center 
bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Event Info</b></td>' +
                  '<td align=center 
bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Login</b></td>'+
                  '<td align=center 
bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>DBName</b></td>'+
                  '<td align=center bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Command</b></td>'+
                  '<td align=center bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>CPUTime</b></td>'+
                  '<td align=center bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>DiskIO</b></td>'+
                  '<td align=center bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>LastBatch</b></td>'+
                  '<td align=center bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>EventTime</b></td></tr>';

Select @Body = (SELECT td= row_number()over(order by I.SPID ),'',       
                        td=I.SPID,'',
                        td= I.EventInfo,'',     
                        td= MAX(I.Login),'',
                        td= I.DBName,'',
                        td= I.Command,'',
                        td= SUM(I.CpuTime),'',
                        td= SUM(I.DiskIO),'',
                        td= I.LastBatch,'',     
                        td= I.EventTime,''
                        FROM  @BusyProcess I
                        WHERE   EventInfo NOT LIKE '---BusyProcess Detection%'
                        --AND EventTime >= 3
                        GROUP BY SPID, EventInfo, DBName, Command, LastBatch, EventTime
                        --HAVING MAX(Login) = 'CureMD'
                        For XML raw('tr'), Elements
                        )
 -- INSERT


-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')


Select @Body = @TableHead + @Body + @TableTail
-- Send mail to DBA Team
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='email', -- change mail address accordingly
    @subject = 'Blocking Session Detected', 

    @body = @Body,
    @body_format = 'HTML' ;

DECLARE @QKILLsp VARCHAR(1000)

SET @QKILLsp= (SELECT DISTINCT '  KILL '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,SPID)
                        FROM  @BusyProcess I
                        WHERE   EventInfo NOT LIKE ' ---BusyProcess Detection%'
                        AND EventTime >= 10 
                        for XML path('')
                        )

EXEC(@QKILLsp) 

END
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `AND loginame <> 'AccountNotToDelete'` to the `WHERE` clause where you populate your table variable?  Or do you still need to monitor those as being busy for some other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting into the advisability of your process, is there any reason why couldn't you simply add a login-based filter to your `INSERT` statement for the `@BusyProcess` table?

```
INSERT  @BusyProcess
    ( 
        SPID, 
        Status, 
        Login, 
        HostName,  
        DBName, 
        Command, 
        CPUTime,
        DiskIO, 
        LastBatch, 
        ProgramName
    )

SELECT 
    spid,
    status,
    loginame,
    hostname,
    DB_NAME(dbid),
    cmd,
    cpu,
    physical_io,
    last_batch,
    program_name 
FROM SYS.SYSPROCESSES
WHERE 
    1 = CASE 
            WHEN Status IN ( 'RUNNABLE', 'SUSPENDED' ) THEN 1 --Transactions that are open not yet committed or rolledback
            WHEN Status = 'SLEEPING' AND open_tran  > 0 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END
    AND cmd NOT LIKE 'BACKUP%'     
    AND LoginName NOT IN 
      (
      -- Your List Here
      )
```

Comment: Is the EXEC(@QKILLsp) actually killing the identified blocks?

Comment: Filtering them from `@BusyProcess` will also filter them from the `EXEC` statement, if that's what you are asking.  As to the validity of the rest of the script, I have no idea - try replacing `EXEC(@QKILLsp)` with `PRINT @QKILLsp ` and seeing if the SQL output does what you expect it to.